# How to read data from Kafka Stream changelog topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I use Kafka Stream to do with my topic A, and I use inMemoryKeyValueStore.

```
builder.addStateStore(Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
           //Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("AccurateADCounts"),
            Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore("AccurateADCounts"),
            Serdes.String(),
            Serdes.Integer()),
            "AccurateADProcess");
```

I trace the Kafka Stream will record the status back to the topic with `${application.id}-${state-store-name}-changelog`

e.g.  `shunwang-streams-filebeat-test-AccurateADCounts-changelog`

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "shunwang-streams-filebeat-test");
```

> To make state stores fault-tolerant and to allow for state store migration without data loss, a state store can be continuously backed up to a Kafka topic behind the scenes.

I try to consumer the topic , it return some unreadable data.

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic shunwang-streams-filebeat-test-AccurateADCounts-changelog --from-beginning --new-consumer
```

return some thing like :

```
Xshell    null
```

Question:

Is any way how to correct read the topic `${application.id}-${state-store-name}-changelog` ?

I know the topic is for Kafka Stream , but I still want to find some way to do this.

Comment: Well, assuming `Xshell` was a key at some point, and the value was `null`, then that record is being deleted from the changelog... Do you have more records?

Comment: I do not think `Xshell` is a key . But I do not know why the data `Xshell` appear here.  I do not delete the key for now , it still return the data `Xshell` ~

Comment: Sorry, I thought you had `--property print.key=true` for some reason. Anyway, if your console doesn't support UTF-8 encoded characters, you would see some weird characters, or possibly just `X`... Can you add a full example of your inputs and maybe what output you're expecting? because `console-consumer` will try to stringify the data regardless, so since it's just binary data, you wouldn't be able to read it easily without some custom code

Comment: 'it's just binary data,'  Ye. That is the point.  The topic is created by kafkastream , means the data is putted by kafkastream, used by kafkastream, as a third consumer , I want to know how to transform the binary data, maybe I should to read the source code of Kafka , maybe u could show me the way about which part of the code I should read or something else,.

Comment: You could start at the unit test that validates the contents of the store. https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/internals/InMemoryKeyValueStoreTest.java

Comment: And I think this is the deserializer you would want https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/internals/ChangedDeserializer.java

Comment: I will try  . Thank u.